# .NET Core: Remove empty array from Json response

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core

I'm having a problem related with the Json response. 
Here's a example of the response:

```
public class ContentModel
{
    public int? Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ContentResultModel> Results { get; set; }
    public FullContentModel Result { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<PaginationModel> Pagination { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ContentCommentsModel> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want the pagination to come in the response, if its empty. For example, for when it's null, I use:

```
options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Is there anything similar, that could solve my problem? I already search, and almost everybody uses a regex expression, but I want to avoid that, and want to use something more straightforward and simple, if its possible.

Even if I say the *pagination* property is null, it always changes to empty.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Newtonsoft Json.NET skip serializing empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320968/can-newtonsoft-json-net-skip-serializing-empty-lists)

Comment: I suspect you search for answers that process the string after it's generated. JSON.NET though contains a *lot* of extension points that allow you to customize how things are serialized

Comment: @DanielBeckmann i think not. Because i don't want to keep doing that everytime i need it. And it will be a lot :\ (if i understand right ofc)

Comment: @BernardoF.Coelho the last answer actually covers your case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos from what I see, it helps me, but, I don't want to make
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, JsonSettings);
every single time. That's my problem. My API is huge, and I would like something to add to startup, that updates globally.

Comment: Can you show the class definition of the response type?

Comment: @DanielBeckmann i've updated the question with the class in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extend your class definition with a `ShouldSerialize` method, to omit the `Pagination` property, when the list is empty. You can find more information in the [Json.Net docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm).

```
public class ContentModel
{
    public int? Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ContentResultModel> Results { get; set; }
    public FullContentModel Result { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<PaginationModel> Pagination { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ContentCommentsModel> Comments { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializePagination()
    {
        // don't serialize the Pagination property, when the list is empty
        return Pagination != null && Pagination.Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Example usage: You then can return an object of the type `ContentModel` in an ApiController and the pagination property won't be present in the JSON response, when the list is null or empty.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<ContentModel> Get()
{
    var model = new ContentModel
    {
        Total = 12
    };

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Comment: Daniel that example is not working for me ... I check the docs, and the difference is that they use JsonConvert.SerializeObject, and I return Json(object).

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebAPI and you return a ContentModel from a ApiController? Or how is your handling done?

Comment: Im using .net core 2.1 web api, and i use like this:
"return StatusCode(200, contentModel);"

Comment: Added an example. Also .net core 2.1.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that there is an option that means you can separate out the concern for "should serialise" into it's own class, thereby maintain SoC.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903151/how-to-omit-empty-collections-when-serializing-with-json-net